# Code that draws a target. Ask the user for input for the location of the target and the diameter of the yellow center

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am having problems trying to draw (in python using turtle) the archery target and asking the user for input for location of the target and diameter of the yellow center. [target image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt0eU.png)

Code I have so far (probably wrong):

```
import turtle

turtle = turtle.Turtle()
def origin_circle(turtle, radius):
turtle.dot(100, 'black')
turtle.dot(75, 'cyan')
turtle.dot(50, 'red')
turtle.dot(25, 'yellow')

for radius in range(100, 200, 10):
origin_circle(turtle, radius)

turtle.hideturtle()
```

Comment: what did you try ? Show your code. Show full error message. Did you try to draw figure with `N` sides using loop with `forwar` and `left` (or `right`)?

Comment: Hi, I executed your code but named the turtle object 'foo' (basically, anything but turtle) and replaced turtle with foo wherever it is being used. Also, added turtle.mainloop() at the end and it works!
Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to get a location and diameter input from the user. Location of the target and diameter of the yellow center. Like this: location = float(input("Enter Location here: ")). But I don't know how and where to put the location and diameter value in my code so that the target moves.

Comment: One think that's wrong with your code is that it is not indented properly — at least not as shown in your question. Indentation is very significant in Python, so please [edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: So... nobody is able to answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

> So... nobody is able to answer my question?

It's not a difficult problem -- you even have a loop you don't need:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def origin_circle(turtle, diameter):
    turtle.dot(diameter * 4, 'black')
    turtle.dot(diameter * 3, 'cyan')
    turtle.dot(diameter * 2, 'red')
    turtle.dot(diameter, 'yellow')

diameter = float(input("Diameter of target center: "))
x_coordinate = float(input("X coordinate of target center: "))
y_coordinate = float(input("Y coordinate of target center: "))

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)

origin_circle(turtle, diameter)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note that `turtle.dot()` takes a *diameter* as input and draws when the pen is *up* or *down* but `turtle.circle()` uses a `radius` and only draws when the pen is *down*.